pyqt5 label position in mainwindow
This is my layout from the Qt Designer:

And this is the output from this

I add image to this label area like this:
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent = None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.boxes = []  # Klonlanmış box'ların listesi

        self.img = QPixmap("box.png").scaled(100, 150)  # Orjinal box resmi
        print( self.img.width(),self.img.height())
        self.ui.image.setPixmap(self.img)

        self.dragging = False  
        self.offset = None  

I want to get position of the click on this label but it gives me the different position from event.pos()
  def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
           print(event.pos())
           print(self.ui.image.mapTo(self, self.ui.image.pos()))
           print(self.ui.image.pos())

This is different
I need to match mause clicking position and label position. I need to detect whether this box is clicked or not. How is this possible in this layout?
I tried this suggestions :
print(self.ui.image.rect().contains(self.ui.image.mapFromGlobal(event.globalPos()))) If I click the anywhere in boxLayoutWidget it gives me True but I want to get True only if I click self.ui.image label
Also I face with very different things.:
If I print this position in MainWindow init functions print(self.ui.image.mapToGlobal(QPoint(0, 0))) I get different result with inside this function :
def mousePressEvent(self, event):
if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
print(self.ui.image.mapToGlobal(QPoint(0, 0)))

self.ui.image.mapFromGlobal(event.globalPos())

This not work. @musicamante I want to match click mause position and self.ui.image position this way I can detect the press on it or not

print(self.ui.image.rect().contains(self.ui.image.mapFromGlobal(event.globalPos())). I strongly suggest you to read the whole documentation of QWidget.

@musicamante I read it and I'm here because I couldn't do it. When I use this             print(self.ui.image.rect().contains(self.ui.image.mapFromGlobal(event.globalPos())))
If I click the anywhere in boxLayoutWidget it gives me True but I want to get True only if I click self.ui.image label

I solve this problem like this:
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent = None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.boxes = []  # Klonlanmış box'ların listesi

        self.original_box = QPixmap("box.png").scaled(100, 150)  # Orjinal box resmi
        # print( self.img.width(),self.img.height())
        print("Before")
        self.ui.image.setPixmap(self.original_box)

        self.dragging = False  # Sürükleme durumu
        self.offset = None  # Sürükleme konumu
        self.ui.image.setFixedSize(self.original_box.width(), self.original_box.height())
        # self.ui.image.setScaledContents(True)
        self.ui.image.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.ui.image.setStyleSheet("QLabel { padding: 0px; }")

After that global position work for me, I need to reduce the padding.

The line I suggested does work. The problem is that the image is smaller than the actual size of QLabel, and the layout sets its geometry based on all the contents, so you assumed that you were clicking outside of the label, but you actually were clicking outside of the image. Another approach (if the label alignment is centered and scaledContents is false) is to get the rectangle of the pixmap, and map it to the center of the label: r = self.ui.image.pixmap().rect() r.moveCenter(self.ui.image.rect().center()) r.contains(self.ui.image.mapFromGlobal(event.globalPos())).

For future reference, ensure that you provide everything we need to understand and reproduce the issue (see [mre]): a single block of all the minimal code required to test the example, and anything data/information required, such as the source image (or at least its size in pixels) and possibly the UI file. Without all that, we can only make assumptions that makes helping you more difficult for us, and getting answers long and annoying for you.

You can use event.globalPos() in conjuction with label corrdinates.
  def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
           print(event.globalPos())
           print(self.ui.image.mapTo(self, self.ui.image.pos()))
           print(self.ui.image.pos())


This gives me this result when I click the left top of box PyQt5.QtCore.QPoint(-1383, 393)
PyQt5.QtCore.QPoint(27, 27)
PyQt5.QtCore.QPoint(9, 9) There are different points. Global points and self.ui.image.pos does not matchü
